# Link in emails trigger campaigns twice

Tags: campaigncreator

We send emails to some people outside of our organizations and there is a button (link) so they can click and that triggers a campaign.

When the link is sent by email, the href value is replaced by another value (i.e. protection.outlook.com/?url=...). So protection.outlook.com hits the page to make sure there is no security issue and then will redirect the user to the actual page.

Problem is that the campaign is triggered twice (one by outlook hitting the page and one by the actual hit to the page.

I am not even sure if this can be fixed but is there anything that can be done to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't much that you can do about it since you are at the mercy of the exchanges servers.   I recommend sending the user to a confirmation page that requires the user to click a button on the page before triggering the campaign. This is really the only way to fix this common issue.

Another way is to look at the user agent.  My company noticed a kind of pattern with it.   I can't remember what it was exactly but look through your Mongo data and you should be able to find one. You can ignore or make these requests go to a confirmation page. Don't 404 these though. The exchange server might interpret it as a malicious email.